# incompatible types in assignment of 'char[10]' to 'char [50]'

Tags: c, arrays, string, incomplete-type

I am always taking these "incompatible types in the assignment of 'const char [5]' to 'char [50]'" or like that problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Lessons{
    char name[50];
    float note;
    int credit;  
}lesson1,lesson2;

int main(){
lesson1.name = "Math";

printf("%s",lesson1.name);

return 0;
}
```

The problem in lesson1.name = "Math";.But i can't solving.

Comment: In C strings (arrays in general) cannot be assigned one to another. They are like pointers, and an array name cannot be an _lvalue_ of an assignment. But they can ne **copied**. Use `strcpy (lesson.name "Math");`, instead.

Answer (score 2):

You cant copy strings in C by assigning them.

You need to use the string copy function (called `strcpy`) from the standard library

then

```
 strcpy(lesson1.name, "Math");
```

The only exception from this rule is initialization of the array by string literal or compound literal.

example:

```
int main()
{
     char str[] = "This is string literal";
     struct Lessons lesson3 = {.name = "This is name",};
}
```

where the literal is copied by the function prologue code.

Comment: it's worth adding that he should use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` for safety reasons.

Comment: @GerardoZinno No it is not. `strncpy` is same unsafe as `strcpy` or even more. C standard library strncpy is a disaster.

Comment: I disagree. The fact that isn't perfect doesn't mean that isn't still way safer than strcpy. Having that bound check is still a protection. One thing is having a string that has been cut since it didn't fit, another is a segmentation fault.

Comment: @GerardoZinno (sorry but I think you have no idea why this function is dangerous - it just replaces one possible UB with another [but the strncpy one is not as obvious and many programmers do not know about it] - both may result in the segfault - but of course do not have to) there is no bound check. You just provide the size - which can be also wrong if you made a mistake. And if the size of the source is larger than the size given by you, it does not nul terminate the destination string. So there is nothing to disagree. Google it. See what Linux developers think (Linus for example)

Comment: In my workflow, when the buffer size was specified with a define, it has saved me many times. The important thing is to read the manual page of the function and know what you are doing. Why would it be less safe than strcpy?

Comment: As for "you have no idea why is dangerous", I think you're referring to the fact it may leave you with a char array instead of a string, but depending on what are the practices followed by you when coding, this can be easily detected.

Comment: @GerardoZinno  I wrote it already. If source is larger than the destination the destination will not be `nul` terminated - ie it will not be a C string anymore. `strncpy` is **not  safe**. It replaces one bad with another

Comment: But that's not a surprise, it's in the manual and you should expect it. Never said it's perfect, but imo it replaces one bad with another bad that's a bit less bad.

Comment: @GerardoZinno it is common opinion https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/strncpy.html https://www.securityfocus.com/bid/10331 https://blog.liw.fi/posts/strncpy/ etc etc

Comment: @GerardoZinno there are no better or worse UBs. Both are dangerous and functions prone to it should not be used

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a string to a buffer using the `=` operator.  You’ll need to use the `strcpy` library function:

```
#include <string.h>
...
strcpy( lesson1.name, “Math” );
```

Comment: it's worth adding that he should use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` for safety reasons.